# Making a table with a foreign key

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm creating a SQL database in Oracle. I have created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE LOC
(
    LID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    CITY VARCHAR(50),
    STREET VARCHAR(50),
    SNUMBER VARCHAR(50)
);
```

And I tried creating a second table that has a foreign key referencing it:

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF
(
    EID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(50),
    SURNAME VARCHAR(50),
    HIREDATE DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (LID) REFERENCES LOC(LID)
);
```

I get this error:

> ORA-00904: "LID": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a foreign key on a column doesn't create the column. You need to create the column first and then define it as a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF(
EID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(50),
SURNAME VARCHAR(50),
HIREDATE DATE,
LID INTEGER
FOREIGN KEY (LID) REFERENCES LOC(LID));
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be either a column definition plus a full constraint definition, or (better in my view) name the column, say what it references and let it inherit the datatype.

(By the way, what's `varchar`?)

```
create table loc
( lid       integer primary key
, city      varchar2(50)
, street    varchar2(50)
, snumber   varchar2(50) );

create table staff
( eid       integer primary key
, name      varchar2(50)
, surname   varchar2(50)
, hiredate  date
, lid       references loc(lid) );
```